# 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libnode.so' - Problem with jniLibs for nodejs-mobile-react-native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, java-native-interface

I have been trying to get `nodejs-mobile-react-native` to work on Android but I'm getting the following error when I tried to build the project:

```
> Task :nodejs-mobile-react-native:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED

Execution failed for task ':nodejs-mobile-react-native:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libnode.so' from inputs:
      - /Users/<me>/projects/react-native/<my project>/node_modules/nodejs-mobile-react-native/android/build/intermediates/merged_jni_libs/debug/out/arm64-v8a/libnode.so
      - /Users/<me>/Projects/react-native/<my project>/node_modules/nodejs-mobile-react-native/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/4a1j5e35/obj/arm64-v8a/libnode.so
     If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
     https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets
```

I have this setup for the project:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-native": "^0.66.3",
"nodejs-mobile-react-native": "^0.6.3",

Gradle version 7.0.2
Java version 11
NDK version 21.4.7075529
CMake version 3.18.1
Android SDK Platform 31 (12)
```

I tried these settings (and without) in my `app/build.gradle` but it didn't work

```
packagingOptions {
  pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libnode.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libnode.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/x86/libnode.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libnode.so'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was that the `packagingOptions` had to be applied to the gradle file of the **nodejs-mobile-react-native** project here

```
/node_modules/nodejs-mobile-react-native/android/build.gradle
```

To do that automatically I had to create a bash script that adds these lines

```js
packagingOptions {
  pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libnode.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libnode.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libnode.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/x86/libnode.so'
}
```

right above the `lintOptions` and invoke that bash script with the `postinstall` script of the `package.json` file.

Comment: Could you provide how you implemented the postinstall please

Comment: 1. Create a bash script that adds these lines let's say `scripts/android/init.sh`
2. In `package.json` add that to the `scripts` folder `"postinstall": ./scripts/android/init.sh`

Comment: answer is not clean

Comment: please show the codes and path.

Comment: `codes and path`. What does that mean? Code of what? 
Do you mean using `sed` command to modify the `build.gradle` file in a bash script? You can Google that.